# How to schedule windows maintaince utility silently?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp, scheduled-tasks

I am working as a system administrator, so i have responsibility to maintain each and every system. But our staff is non technical so each and every time i started some system maintenance utility like disc error, disc fragment, CHKDSK etc, they cancel the process,as they do not know about it.
so i want to schedule these utility without knowing them that it is running( in the background)
two things i want
 that any utility window comes in foreground 
 these utility should run in schedule like once every week without any one notice it

Answer (score 0):

Actually Windows 7 has a built-in scheduled task to run defrag silently.
http://www.verboon.info/2011/10/changing-the-windows-7-scheduled-defrag-task/

You can use task scheduler to trigger chckdsk.exe etc. as well.

Comment: u did not understand, i knew about the task scheduler, but the thing with it is it open a window of disc defragment tool or disc error tool etc, this is the problem for me because my staff unknowingly cancel the process window..so that is why i want them to run in background without anyone noticing it

Comment: have you tried to run the task as "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM"?

Answer (score 0):

To expand on @bin-da 's answer:

The built in Task Scheduler that you are already familiar with probably can do what you need / want.

#### General Tab

When you go through the UI wizard to create a new task, the [General] tab has some settings you will want to use:

1. "(x) Run whether the user is logged on or not"
2. "[x] Hidden"

#### Triggers Tab

When you enter the [Triggers] tab, select a schedule time when users are not expected to be using the system:

1. Set time to start at a low use period (e.g. 2 am).

#### Conditions Tab

On the [Conditions] tab, set the following:

1. "[x] Wake the computer to run this task."

If you use those settings, you can probably get your maintenance scripts to run without interference by or even the notice of your users.